# Gulp - Delete empty folders recursively

Tags: gulp

I want to delete all folders and subfolders inside of a given directory if they only contain folders and no files. Is there an easy way to do that?

What I found until now:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-recursive-folder
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-count
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`delete-empty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delete-empty):

```
gulp.task('delete-empty-directories', function() {
  deleteEmpty.sync('foo/');
});
```

This recursively deletes all empty folders below `foo/`.

Comment: I used this for a while, but it isn't working now with node version 18.12.1 and gulp version 4.0.2

Comment: Version 3.0.0 of this package not working. Downgrade to 2.0.0 and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough start, so you'll just need to loop for recursion I guess.

```
var modules = {
    gulp       : require('gulp'),
    fs         : require('fs'),
    path       : require('path'),
    del        : require('del'),
    map        : require('map-stream')
};

modules.gulp.task('folder-delete', function() {

    // get folder list inside of the dir passed in
    function getFolders(dir) {
        return modules.fs.readdirSync(dir)
          .filter(function(file) {
            return modules.fs.statSync(modules.path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
          });
    }

    var dir     = '../src/',  // (update with your path to the root folder)
        folders = getFolders(dir),
        hasFile = 0;

    var folderMap = folders.map(function(folder) {
        hasFile = 0; // reset for each folder

        return modules.gulp.src(dir + folder + '/**/*')
            .pipe(modules.map(function(file, cb) {
                hasFile = 1;
                cb(null, file);
            }))
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log(hasFile, ' - ', folder);

                if (!hasFile) {
                    modules.del([dir + folder], { force: true }).then(function() {
                        console.log('Deleted ' + dir + folder);
                    });
                }
            })
    });

    return folderMap;
});
```

Basically, this is setting the directory at ../src/, getting the folders at the root of that dir, then runs the src under those directories.  It then uses map to see if there was a file added to the stream, then updates a variable if so.  After the task finishes and if the variable has not been updated, then it will delete the folder.

As stated above, you could probably just loop through the directories for the recursion (or you could use one of the plugins you've mentioned).

Comment: Thx. I will try the solution of "Sven Schoenung" first because I prefer more dependencies than more code for the moment.

Comment: no problem.  I was in the mood to write it out.  Let us know if it works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution, which uses the `delete-empty` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delete-empty), doesn't work for me ([and for others too](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/delete-empty/issues/20)). Plus, the creator seems to have stopped maintaining the package (last update 3 years ago).

What works just fine, and probably is much more future save, is a combination of  `sync-exec` and the OS `find` command.

```js
const syncExec = require("sync-exec")

syncExec("find sample/directory/ -type d -empty -delete")
```